# How to read already exiting data from firebase database before writing in Android using java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app. I am using Firebase for backend services. I want to authenticate people based on their phone numbers. Multiple user account should not be possible for a phone number.

Database structure is as shown below.

[image]

If another user enters the same phone number, we should not allow to login. So I wrote the code as below

On click of the button I tried to read all the user info and save it in a list.Then check the existing phone numbers in database with the current phone number. If data already exists then data won't be stored. Else data would be stored

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   EditText E1, E2, E3;
   Button B1,B2;
    String phone;
String exist="not_exist";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    phone = intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
    onclick();
}
void onclick() {
    E1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.L_Name);
    E2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.L_Password);
    E3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.L_Confirm_Password);
    B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    B1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View V) {
                    DatabaseReference mreadDatabase;
                    mreadDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
                    mreadDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<String> username = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<String> phonearray = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<String> pswr = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                                list.add(user);
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                username.add(i,list.get(i).getname());
                                phonearray.add(i,list.get(i).getphone());
                                pswr.add(i,list.get(i).getpswr());
                                Log.e("in copy section","in copy section");
                                Log.e("username.get(i)", username.get(i));
                                Log.e("phonearray.get(i)", phonearray.get(i));
                                Log.e("pswr.get(i)", pswr.get(i));
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                Log.e("in check section","in check section");
                                Log.e("phone",phone);
                                Log.e("username.get(i)", username.get(i));
                                if (phone == phonearray.get(i)) {
                                    exist = "exist";
                                    Log.e("exist", exist);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                    });
                    if (E2.getText().toString().equals(E3.getText().toString()) ) {
                        Log.e("in store section","in store section");
                        Log.e("exist",exist);
                        if (exist == "not_exist") {
                            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                            String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                            User user = new User(E1.getText().toString(), phone, E2.getText().toString());
                            mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Login Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            Log.e("write", "write");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Phone number already registered.Check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                     else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Password Mismatch.Please check"+E2.getText().toString()+E2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

I tried to use addListenerForSingleValueEvent and addValueEventListener.It reads all the data that is in database, but it does only after saving the current data. I mean read is done only after the write is executed. Please let me know where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.hasChild("name")) {
 // run some code
 }
 }
});
```

**.hasChild** will tell you whether the user is already there or not. If it is there than you can proceed to login and if it doesn't then add user into the database.

Comment: If i make change in addListenerForSingleValueEvent,it will get invoked only after my current data is saved(as per the code i wrote).How should I modify the code so that read takes place before write?

Comment: First try with Read only that whether you are able to read data or not. Then move to writing data. Once you will know that here reading of data ends then you can start 'writing'